# change the pattern of vibration in Firefox OS app

Tags: firefox-os

I want to provide a different pattern of vibration for the notification from my app . Is it possible to do that and , if possible , how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Ishwar Patil  
You can change the number series so as to change the vibration pattern..Try this code:

```
 var vibrate = document.querySelector("#vibrate");
    if (vibrate) {
        vibrate.onclick = function () {
            navigator.vibrate(2000);
            /*
                Possible values:
                On/off pattern:
                navigator.vibrate([200, 100, 200, 100]);

                Turn off vibration
                navigator.vibrate(0);
            */
        };
```